# Avoid jQuery Race Condition

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery.getJSON(root + "Communication/ProcessCreateMessage", data);
return location.href = '@Url.Content("~")Communication/Index';
```

Here is my code which make a race condition in firefox, the second command starts before the first one finishs so my jQuery.getJSON function doesn't work. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the location to be changed after you have created a message server side. If so, use the complete method which will execute a function after the JSON has been submitted and a response returned

```
jQuery.getJSON(root + "Communication/ProcessCreateMessage", data).complete(function () {
    location.href = '@Url.Content("~")Communication/Index';
});
```